# ExecuteStreamCommand with Wait/Notify Apache Nifi + Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-nifi

I am using Apache NiFi with Spark.

I am submitting Spark jobs to Spark cluster using ExecuteStreamCommand processor.

I would like to wait for a Spark job to finish before starting other processors.

However, in my case the processors start simultaniously.

You can see workflow on the image below.

[image: Overall Flow]

**DownloadFromDB** proccess group(Contains Spark ExecuteStreamCommand ) should finish before CleanTempFiles and MergeFilesAndUploadToDB start. However, **CleanTempFiles** start before **DownloadFromDB** is finished.

Below is the **DownloadFromDB** process group (MergeFilesAndUploadToDB has the same processors, just different Spark job submitted).

[image]

Below is **CleanTempFiles** process group
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier pattern instead of wait/notify: have the Spark job publish a message to a queue of some sort (JMS, Kafka, etc.) that will give you full control from Spark to signal that the next step is ready.